# On which window / document event should a component be initialized?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

### Small example component (for all following examples):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 v-on:click="handleClick">Test</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class TestComponent extends Vue {
  created() {
    console.log("Initialized vue component");
  }

  public handleClick() {
    console.log("Clicked element");
  }
}
</script>
```

Markup of element in DOM of main page, where the Vue Component should be loaded to:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

---

### Example 1: Instantiation of component in main.js, without respecting any window / document events:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import TestComponent from "./TestComponent";
const test = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  components: {
    'test-component': TestComponent
  }
});
```

Console output:

After load: "Initialized vue component" / On Click: **nothing**

---

### Example 2: Wait for window loaded:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  const test = new Vue({
    el: '#test',
    components: {
    'test-component': TestComponent
    }
  });
});
```

After load: "Initialized vue component" / On Click: "Clicked element"

---

### Example 3: Or wait for document load?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const test = new Vue({
    el: '#test',
    components: {
      'test-component': TestComponent
    }
  });
});
```

After load: "Initialized vue component" / On Click: "Clicked element"

---

### Example 4: $mount

```
const test = new Vue({
  components: {
    TestComponent
  },
  render: (h) => h(TestComponent),
}).$mount('#test');
```

After load: "Initialized vue component" / On Click: "Clicked element"

---

### Example 5: $mount after DOMContentLoaded

```
const test = new Vue({
  components: {
    TestComponent
  },
  render: (h) => h(TestComponent),
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  test.$mount('#test');
});
```

After load: "Initialized vue component" / On Click: "Clicked element"

---

### Questions:

- Is there a difference for a vue component on the time of being initialized? (DOMContentLoaded vs. window.loaded)
- Is there another reason why the click event is not firing in the first example?

Comment: Can you please show the code (layout) where you add your component on the page? Or do you use it somehow different?

Comment: Yes. I added above. It is just a div with the id "test". I guess, I do something wrong in mounting the element properly. If I kickstart a new project with vue cli, there is no need to respect any global load or ready events.

Comment: It's still not clear how you load your component into this div. I don't see any code loading the component into exactly this div.

Comment: I thought, that el: #test mounts the component to the dom element with ID test. So I guess, I was mounting the component not correct. I added two other examples with $mount. I think, that answers my question. As click triggers in both ways, I guess, there is no need to wait till DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: What problems do these questions try to solve?

Comment: In some cases, the click event is not fired.